# Erro referência indefinida - C++

Tags: c++, perl

Olá! Estou tentando compilar meu programa em C++ (ele chama uma função escrita na linguagem Perl) e ele está retornando uma longa lista de erros "referência indefinida":

```
    testeperl2principal.o: na função `S_croak_memory_wrap':
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0xa): referência indefinida para `PL_memory_wrap'
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0x14): referência indefinida para `Perl_croak_nocontext'
testeperl2principal.o: na função `main':
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0x3d): referência indefinida para `perlWrapper::perlWrapper()'
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0x4c): referência indefinida para `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0x64): referência indefinida para `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
testeperl2principal.cpp:(.text+0x73): referência indefinida para `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
(....)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Sou novo com C++ e todo esse processo de compilação... Muito obrigado!

Códigos:

```
//perlWrapper.h
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class perlWrapper{
    public:
        perlWrapper();
        ~perlWrapper();
        void runInterpreterWithPerlFile (char *file);
        int getMathResult(int a, string perlFunc);
    private:
        PerlInterpreter *my_perl;
        char *my_argv[2];
};
```

.cpp:

```
//perlWrapper.cpp
#include "perlWrapper.h"
using namespace std;
perlWrapper::perlWrapper(){
    PERL_SYS_INIT3(NULL,NULL,NULL);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct( my_perl );
    PL_exit_flags = PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
}
perlWrapper::~perlWrapper(){
    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);
    PERL_SYS_TERM();
}
void perlWrapper::runInterpreterWithPerlFile(char *file){
    string a = "";
    char * S = new char[a.length()+1];
    strcpy(S,a.c_str());
    char *my_argv[] = {S, file};
    perl_parse(my_perl,0,2,my_argv,(char**)NULL);
    perl_run(my_perl);
}
int perlWrapper::getMathResult(int valor, string perlFunc){
    dSP;
    ENTER;
    SAVETMPS;
    PUSHMARK(SP);
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(valor)));
    PUTBACK;
    call_pv(perlFunc.c_str(),G_SCALAR);
    SPAGAIN;
    int resultado = POPi;
    PUTBACK;
    FREETMPS;
    LEAVE;  
    return resultado;
}
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "perlWrapper.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    perlWrapper perlwrapper;
    string a = "perlMath.pl";
    char * S = new char[a.length()+1];
    strcpy(S,a.c_str());
    perlwrapper.runInterpreterWithPerlFile(S);
    cout << perlwrapper.getMathResult(1, "multiplyByTwo");
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=$(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts)
LD=g++
LDFLAGS=$(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts)
all: testeperl2principal
.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
perlteste2principal:  perlWrapper.o testeperl2principal.o
                    $(LD) -o $@ $? $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f testeperl2principal *.o
```